# Running git reset --hard on my repo/branch does --NOT-- take me to the last commit. How to fix?

Tags: git

as above. Might be best explain with screenshot/example.

---

Here's the latest commits for my test branch.

[image]

Here are the console commands.

- If you refer to the first git log, the last commit on the branch is "42a90f86f992ca3e346597f9f639ef4cb7e3cf19" (which should correspond to the commit in the screenshot).
- I then run git reset --hard, this should take me back to the same commit but for some reason, it's resetting to a much older commit.

> ```
> $ git branch
> * test
>
> $ git pull origin test
> From bitbucket.org:flinderswebtransformation/scholarships-system
>  * branch            test       -> FETCH_HEAD
> Already up-to-date.
> $ git log
> commit 42a90f86f992ca3e346597f9f639ef4cb7e3cf19
> Merge: 6ace73c ef6af98
> Author: my-user <my-user@my-host.com>
> Date:   Tue Sep 21 06:37:35 2021 +0000
>
>     Merged in dev (pull request #22)
>     
>     changed datasources for dev and test
>
> commit ef6af98d28aebd00e2d0a80c775d31c35d243fee
> Author: my-user <my-user@my-host.com>
> Date:   Tue Sep 21 16:06:46 2021 +0930
>
>     changed datasources for dev and test
>
> $ git reset --hard origin/test
> HEAD is now at 4b2c4a3 Merged in bug/SP-1790-remove-references-css-js-and-etc (pull request #17)
>
> $ git log
> commit 4b2c4a36467fd6711e8a7193471c67335b59e14d
> Merge: a0fd07e 868b500
> Author: my-user <my-user@my-host.com>
> Date:   Mon Aug 5 01:00:55 2019 +0000
>
>     Merged in bug/SP-1790-remove-references-css-js-and-etc (pull request #17)
>     
>     fixed references to assets and updated links to use AEM ones
>     
>     Approved-by: my-user <my-user@my-host.com>
>
> commit 868b5006adea72c1e69ec54266caf13c4870cb5e
> Author: my-user <my-user@my-host.com>
> Date:   Mon Aug 5 10:15:26 2019 +0930
>
>     fixed references to assets and updated links to use AEM ones
>
> $
> ```

Comment: DId you tried this `git reset --hard 'your SHA Commit id'` i.e `git reset --hard 'ef6af98'`

Comment: Your local `origin/test` is likely out of date compared to what's on the remote. Try running `git fetch` before resetting to `origin/test`.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio wouldn't running git pull fetch the latest changes? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --hard HEAD~1` ( this will delete your last commit and file too )

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`git reset --hard 'your SHA Commit id'`

Example:  `git reset --hard 'ef6af98'`